# split() function is deleting rest of the string after comma

Tags: .net, vb.net, string, parsing, split

I am using split function to add data to data table from csv file
my strings are like this

`"50000007;Bxxxx Kxxx - Sxxx Fx. xxxx;423283; ;423292;1;          ;700000004;T;"`

and I use this code

```
  x = dt.Rows.Count
    For i As Integer = 0 To x - 1
       Dim Data As String = dt.Rows(i).Item(0)
       Dim words As String() = Data.Split(New Char() {";"c})
       bilgi.Rows.Add(words)
    Next
```

and its working for thousands of lines but if string come with comma
for example

`"50000007;Bxxxx**,** Kxxx - Sxxx Fx. xxxx;423283; ;423292;1;          ;700000004;T;"`

after split my string array only (`"50000007","Bxxxx"`) and rest is gone and continue to next line.

can anyone help me solve this issue?

Comment: How are you loading the csv file into the data table? The way you are using it, `String.split` will only split on semicolons. If "the rest is gone and continue to next line", then "the rest" is already placed in the following row before you even enter the `for` loop.

Comment: That's *not* how `Split` works. Please post a *complete and minimal* example - ie  *don't* involve the data table. As it is, you probably load the CSV using `,` as the field separator, resulting in the first column containing the first two strings instead of the entire line

Comment: I use this code to read csv file `Dim sConn = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & yol & _
            ";Extended Properties='text;HDR=Yes;FMT=Delimited(;)';"
Dim dt As New DataTable() '";Extended Properties=""text;HDR=Yes;FMT=Delimited(;)"";"
 Using adapt As New OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [" & dosya & "]", sConn)
adapt.Fill(dt)
End Using`

Comment: @Groo yes I like to split semicolons. I as i mentioned it is working. But if thre is a comma between semicolons, ignores rest of data and continue next row. CSV file contains almost 200 rows and rest are ok

Comment: @Murat - Your provider is splitting at the `,`. Your code is only getting the first part of the line **before** you split by the `;`. The rest of the line would be at `dt.Rows(i).Item(1)` (and maybe more if there are more `,`'s).

Comment: @Enigmativity I'll try to see rest of data as you sugested. but isn't `Delimited(;)` mean "ignore the default delimiter and use semicolon"?

Comment: @Enigmativity  You are right. thanks

Answer (score 2):

*Disclaimer: This is more of a comment than an answer so please treat as such*

I think the code you posted is not complete because a simple test does not produce the output you describe:

```
    Dim Data As String = "50000007;Bxxxx**,** Kxxx - Sxxx Fx. xxxx;423283; ;423292;1;          ;700000004;T;"
    Dim words As String() = Data.Split(New Char() {";"c})
    For Each word In words
        Debug.WriteLine("word:" & word)
    Next
```

Outputs:

```
word:50000007
word:Bxxxx**,** Kxxx - Sxxx Fx. xxxx
word:423283
word: 
word:423292
word:1
word:          
word:700000004
word:T
word:
```

Comment: I didn't tried with string, I always read from csv file using OleDb with "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & path &        ";Extended Properties='text;HDR=Yes;FMT=Delimited(;)';" connection string. Perhaps I am making mistake while reading csv file.